# How can I pass data from python_callable to on_success_callback?

Tags: callback, airflow

I have a DAG with a `PythonOperator` calling a function. I also have a callback function. I want to pass some information from the callable to the callback. How can I do this?

I tried using the context dictionary:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pprint import pprint
from airflow import DAG
from airflow.operators.python_operator import PythonOperator

args = {"owner": "airflow",
        "start_date": datetime(2019, 11, 18)}

dag = DAG(dag_id="context_demo",
          default_args=args)


def test_callable(**context):
    print('Starting callable...')
    context['z_my_var'] = 'my_val'
    pprint(context)
    print('Callable finished.')


def test_callback(context):
    print('Starting callback...')
    pprint(context)
    print('Callback finished.')


print_exec_date = PythonOperator(
    task_id="print_exec_date",
    python_callable=test_callable,
    on_success_callback=test_callback,
    provide_context=True,
    dag=dag,
)
```

But the value I set in `test_callable` does not persist into `test_callback`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I use xCom as a work around. Here is a complete [example](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/example_dags/example_xcom.py) from Official airflow Docs. You can read more about xcome [here](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html?highlight=xcom#xcoms).

```
# inside a PythonOperator called 'pushing_task'
def push_function():
   return value

# inside another PythonOperator where provide_context=True
def pull_function(**context):
    value = context['task_instance'].xcom_pull(task_ids='pushing_task')
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid using Xcom since it's generally meant for passing data between tasks. I was assuming that the callback is always executed on the same machine as the `Operator`.